# Firebase Initialization Error in React: 'Uncaught TypeError

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm encountering an error in my React application related to **Firebase**. The error message is:

> firebase.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'initializeApp')

I've double-checked my Firebase initialization, and everything seems to be in order. Can you help me understand what might be causing this error and how to resolve it?

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth'

export const auth = firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBIqMayX9xVEqPAl84yJqMlbThIBjaXNtQ",
    authDomain: "unichat-b40da.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "unichat-b40da",
    storageBucket: "unichat-b40da.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "536895363702",
    appId: "1:536895363702:web:304983fb3e9f21e9a81d57"
  }).auth();
```

I took help from Chatgpt but didn't work. I even tried to resolve it by regenerating the app configuring object but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
const firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "Your code",
authDomain: "Your code",
projectId: "Your code",
storageBucket: "Your code",
messagingSenderId: "Your code",
appId: "Your code",
measurementId: "Your code"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
```

Try to replace the code like this. This might help.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I used Firebase in my NextJS application.

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
}

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
```

**Version** in package.json:

```
"firebase": "^10.5.0",
```

Reference: https://github.com/tonystrawberry/matomeishi-next.jp/blob/main/app/firebase.ts